# Get modified url in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code:

```
import urllib.parse

url1 = 'http://example-number.mysite.com/api'
number = '//-1'
url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url1,number)
print(url)
```

Result I am trying to get is: 
http://example-1.mysite.com/api

Is it possible to do this using urljoin? Or should I just use join to do it?

Comment: Its a string anyway. So why not use `'url' + '//1'`

Comment: Seems like you want to replace _number_ with _1_? If so simply go with `url1.replace('number', number)`. If that's not your intention, please refine your question.

Comment: @TobiasLorenz - yes that is the intention, I am new to python but what you said make absolute sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might experiment with these:

```
n = 1
# in python 3.6
url = f'http://example-{n}.mysite.com/api'
# with format
url = 'http://example-{}.mysite.com/api'.format(n)
# with %
url = 'http://example-%s.mysite.com/api' % n
```